# Fullscreen BG video that scales

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to get this background video to cover the viewport regardless of the screen size. I've got it working if the screen is wide enough:

[image]

But if the screen is too narow, I get empty bars on top and bottom:
[image]

I want it to cover the viewport. Here's my code:

```css
.video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: 2s opacity ease;
    transition: 2s opacity ease;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}

.video-foreground, .video-background iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none; 
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
    <section class="full-height-outer home-banner loading" id="home-banner-box">
        <div class="video-background">   
            <div class="video-foreground" id="YouTubeBackgroundVideoPlayer">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <H1 id="title" class="title">This is the title of my site</H1>
            <p class="subtitle">And this is a great subtitle that describes what this page is all about.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Any tips?

Comment: maybe you could use something like [this](https://vodkabears.github.io/vide/)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to code it myself rather than use something pre-built.

Answer (score 0):

use object-fit. i don't see where are you using iframe or video so.use it on your video wrapper or video or iframe. it will make your video cover all the screen

```
 object-fit: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that I'm using a YouTube video. The size is set in the JavaScript. Using ojbect-fit: cover merely turns the white bars into black ones. The YouTube player now covers the screen, but the aspect ratio of the video still causes the black bars on top and bottom.

The way I've fixed it, for now, is by making the dimensions in the JavaScrpt really big, and adjusting the CSS. The negative margin cuts of the video information on top and on the bottom. I still feel like there would be a better way to do it.

You can see the live version here: http://spfict.com/

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('YouTubeBackgroundVideoPlayer', {
      videoId: 'rEagPJY9hwY', // YouTube Video ID
      width: 2249,               // Player width (in px)
      height: 1265,              // Player height (in px)
      playerVars: {
        playlist: 'rEagPJY9hwY',
          autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
          autohide: 1,
          disablekb: 1, 
          controls: 0,        // Hide pause/play buttons in player
          showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
          modestbranding: 0,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
          loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
          fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
          autohide: 0,         // Hide video controls when playing
          rel: 0,
          enablejsapi: 1
      },
      events: {
        onReady: function(e) {
            e.target.mute();
            e.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd1080');
        },
        onStateChange: function(e) {
          if(e && e.data === 1){
              var videoHolder = document.getElementById('home-banner-box');
              if(videoHolder && videoHolder.id){
                videoHolder.classList.remove('loading');
              }
          }else if(e && e.data === 0){
            e.target.playVideo()
          }
        }
      }
  });
}
```

```css
.video-foreground, .video-background iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: -60px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none; 
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    z-index: -10;
    -webkit-transition: 2s opacity ease;
    transition: 2s opacity ease;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
        <section class="full-height-outer home-banner loading" id="home-banner-box">
            <div class="video-foreground" id="YouTubeBackgroundVideoPlayer"></div>
            <div>
                <H1 id="title" class="title">This is the title of my site</H1>
                <p class="subtitle">And this is a great subtitle that describes what this page is all about.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
```